# Problem with comment in strategy.close. Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Hello. I have a problem with put "comment" on strategy.close. I would be very grateful for your help!

Error: Cannot call `strategy.close` with arguments (literal string, comment=literal string); available overloads: strategy.close(const string, series[bool]) => void

```
if longClose or not in_longCondition
averageLongs := 0
totalLongs := 0.0
sectionLongs := 0
sectionLongConditions := 0

if shortClose or not in_shortCondition
averageShorts := 0
totalShorts := 0.0
sectionShorts := 0
sectionShortConditions := 0

if testPeriod()

strategy.entry("Long", 1, when=longCondition, comment="Long")
strategy.entry("Short", 0,  when=shortCondition, comment="Short")

strategy.close("Long",  when=longClose, comment="Close Long")
strategy.close("Short", when=shortClose, comment="Close Short")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation, the strategy.close function doesn't accept the `when` parameter

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}close](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dclose)

Replace it with a if statement

```
if longClose
    strategy.close("Long", comment="Close Long")

if shortClose
    strategy.close("Short", comment="Close Short")
```